# Pass SNMP trap packet to a php daemon on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, php, daemon, snmp

I have a Ubuntu server which is collecting incoming SNMP traps. Currently these traps are handled and logged using a PHP script.

file `/etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf`

```
traphandle default /home/svr/00-VHOSTS/nagios/scripts/snmpTrap.php
```

This script is quite long and it contains many database operations. Usually the server receives thousands of traps per day and therefore this script is taking too much CPU time. My understand is this is due to high start-up cost of the php script every-time when a trap received.

I got a request to re-write this and I was thinking of running this script as a daemon. I can create an Ubuntu daemon. My question is how can I pass  trap-handler to this daemon using `snmptrapd.conf` file?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your question actually confused me, I believe you should move away from using a php script to handle the snmptrapd service.

That file ([/etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/snmptrapd.conf)), is used by the [snmptrapd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/snmptrapd) service which can be enabled at whatever run level you wish (3, 4, 5) and can be configured to log traps to MySQL, so there is no need to create a separate daemon.

On another note perhaps a small shell script would be more efficient than trying to handle the trap by initializing the PHP interpreter, loading the SNMP, MySQL & additional extensions. Here is a [simple example](http://www.nongnu.org/quagga/docs/docs-multi/Handling-SNMP-Traps.html), though you would definitely need to add the database handling (which you can use my [examples](https://github.com/jas-/node-dhcp-manager/blob/master/install/install#L104-L154) to accomplish).

With that being said if you still wish to implement a solution with PHP you should probably research the available [SNMP extension for PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.snmp.php)

Comment: Thanks for the answer jas. Let me make it clear for you. My server receives thousands of traps per hour. Every single trap is processed and logged by this PHP script. For 1000 traps, system will initialize and and load this script 1000 times. Like you said, this is taking too much resources from server. My plan is to keep this script running as a daemon so it wont need to load every time when a trap comes in.

Problem is I don't know how to pass incoming trap packet to running PHP daemon script.

Comment: As I mentioned trying to implement a secondary service to handle an existing service (snmptrapd) doesn't really make a lot of sense.

Rewritting the handler script being used to move away from PHP or another interpreted language and strictly use a shell script will be much more efficient and lower the amount of memory and system resources to perform the database inserts you wish to perform (or simply configure the snmpdtrap.conf file for mysql logging, which is what it was designed for).